# How to create web client for wshttpbinding WCF service in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, wcf

I am a `.net` developer.I had created a `WCF` service having `wshttpbinding`.I want to consume this in a java application using eclipse. please provide suggestion or any other way to create client for WCF service having `wshttpbinding` in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netbeans Eclipse does not provide drag and drop features for WCF services using wshttpbinding security. If you really want to create a client for the same, you have to write your own classes which can adhere to wshttpbinding security protocols

Besides, I hope the link below can help you tremendously :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/777036/Consuming-WCF-Service-in-Java-Client